# Attack Xss on website MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

I have problem with bind data to view MVC.

Suppose my *Content* bellow:

```
<strong>Code here!</strong>
```

If i use Html.Raw(*Content*) when bind data to view i will receive result: **Code here!**.

And if i use Html.Raw(Html.Encode(*Content*)) return result: `<strong>Code here!</strong>`

But if my *Content* bellow:

```
<script>alert("Code here!")</script>
```

If i use Html.Raw(*Content*) when bind data to view script above will execute.
If i use Html.Raw(Html.Encode(*Content*)) return result:

```
<script>alert("Code here!")</script>
```

How to bind data is HTML to view on MVC and not attacked Xss

Comment: Hi you can refer this link : http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2015/04/12/How-to-Handle-Cross-Site-Scripting-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.aspx

Comment: Thanks @SunilKumar, it is great!